# Rails: To normalize or not to normalize for few values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Assuming in a Rails app connected to a Postgres database, you have a table called 'Party', which can have less than 5 well-defined party_types such as 'Person' or 'Organization'.

Would you store the party_type in the Party table (e.g. party.party_type = 'Person') or normalize it (e.g. party.party_type = 1 and party_type.id = 1 / party_type.name = 'Person')? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If party type can be defined in code, I'll definitely go with the names "Person" etc.

If you expect such types will be dynamically added by admin/user, and have such GUI for it, then modelling it and set it like `party.party_type = 1`

Of course there will be a db storage/performance consideration between "1" VS "Person", but that's too minor to considerate when the app is not that big.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. Are you treating these types *generically* or not?<sup>1</sup>
2. Do you display the type to the user?

If the answer to (1) is "yes", then just adding a row in the table is clearly preferable to changing a constraint and/or your application code.

If the answer to (2) is "yes", then storing a human-readable label in the database may be preferable to translating to human-readable text in the application code.

So in a nutshell, you'd *probably* want to have a separate table. On the other hand, if all types are known in advance and you just use them to drive specific paths of your application logic without directly displaying to user, then separate table may be superfluous - just define the appropriate CHECK to restrict the field to valid values and clearly document each value.

---

*<sup>1</sup> In other words, can you add a new type and the logic of your application will continue to work, or you also need to change the application logic?*